# Computing the matrix condition number: forward stability necessary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say the algorithm *Alg1* to compute the condition number of a matrix uses an algorithm *Alg2* for computing SVD. The algorithm *Alg2* is backward stable. If I apply the algorithm *Alg1* on an ill-conditioned matrix would it return the correct condition number? It does not make sense to me that it would...

I would expect the algorithm is FORWARD stable in order for this to happen. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't a questions about mathematics, but instead about a particular commercial software product, and hence should be closed.

Comment: Generally speaking condition numbers are indeed harder to calculate for more poorly conditioned matrices.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I took matlab as an example. The question is about the backward/forward stability of numerical algorithms when applied to ill-conditioned matrices.

Comment: I urge you to re-cast the question without reference to particular software.  You'll more likely focus on the core issues and get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SVD algorithms are [backward stable](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node97.html) in the sense that the estimates $\hat{\sigma}_i$ of the singular values $\sigma_1\geq\ldots\geq\sigma_n>0$ of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ are such that
$$
|\sigma_i-\hat{\sigma}_i|\leq c\epsilon \sigma_1
$$
for some "moderate" constant $c$ depending on the dimensions of the matrix and $\epsilon$ is the machine precision (in other words, there's an $\hat{A}$ such that $\|A-\hat{A}\|_2\leq c\epsilon$ with singular values $\hat{\sigma}_i$).
Consequently,
$$
\sigma_i-c\epsilon\sigma_1\leq\hat{\sigma}_i\leq\sigma_i+c\epsilon\sigma_1.
$$

Now let's see what happens when you plug these estimates to the formula for the spectral condition number. Let's also assume that $A$ is not *too ill-conditioned*, for example, let
$$
c\epsilon\kappa\leq K, \quad \kappa=\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_n},
$$
for some $K<1$.
We get
$$
\hat{\kappa}=\frac{\hat{\sigma}_1}{\hat{\sigma}_n}
\leq\frac{(1+c\epsilon)\sigma_1}{\sigma_n-c\epsilon\sigma_1}
=\frac{(1+c\epsilon)\kappa}{1-c\epsilon\kappa}
\leq\frac{1+c\epsilon}{1-K}\kappa.
$$
Similarly, we can get a lower bound which gives
$$
\frac{1-c\epsilon}{1+K}\leq\frac{\hat{\kappa}}{\kappa}\leq\frac{1+c\epsilon}{1-K}.
$$

So unless your matrix is close to being numerically singular, the computed condition number is still pretty accurate depending on how ill-conditioned the matrix is. If $\hat{\kappa}$ is close to $1/\epsilon\approx 10^{16}$, the matrix is very likely to be numerically singular and the estimate might be garbage.

Answer (score 1):

A backward stable algorithm gives you the right answer to a perturbed problem. If your original problem is ill conditioned, then the solution is sensitive to changes in the input. In particular, the solution of your original problem and the solution of the perturbed problem can be very different. Without additional information, there is no reason to suspect that the computed condition number is a good approximation of the exact condition number.